# Increase precision in Excel

Tags: excel, precision

I'm attempting to display **exactly** the first 100 powers of 2 (e.g. 1,2,4,8,16...) in a column in Excel. Unfortunately, once I get up to about 2 raised to the 50th, I'm hit by the Excel limitation of only working with 15 digits - hence, when Excel multiplies 2^49 * 2 I get the wrong answer:

562949953421312.00 * 2 **!=** 1125899906842620.00

I have tried the Excel option "Set Precision as Displayed", but this doesn't seem to help.  I suppose it makes sense that there needs to be an upper numeric limit somewhere, but it seems that there should be a way of multiplying large numeric strings, no?

562949953421312 * 2 == 112589990684262**4**

Comment: This is better off asked on super user, but its a [dupe](https://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel) over there.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: There is a way, but it involves using VBA to develop methodology that can handle those values that are outside of Excel's limits of precision.  And add-in was developed years ago to do just that.  It is not supported, but still runs, with some limitations, even on Office 365 (at least the 32 bit version -- I dunno about the 64 bit version).  Do an internet search for **xNumbers**.  It is probably still downloadable from someplace. BTW, `2^100` => `1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376` according to xNumbers.

Answer (score 0):

Excel cannot accurately represent numbers that do not fit into 64 bits. To represent numbers beyond 2^64 (you want to reach 2^100) would require more bits, therefore Excel will lose precision with such numbers.

This is an internal limitation of excel, and you should use a different tool to get exact results. Read the corresponding [knowledge base article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) for more details - there is even a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) to describe the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the number in the IFERROR function

```
=IFERROR("1201305162827683","1201305162827683")
```